# Format the selected series in Chart in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I would like to create the macro which will format the selected "DATA LABELS"  in chart in powerpoint. Below is my code. But the problem is Im not able to write code for selected "Data Labels". Please assist

```
Sub testSelection2()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim count As Integer
Dim left_count As Double
Dim Selected_Series As Integer

Dim PPoint As Integer

Set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

count = shp.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.count

For i = 1 To count
    shp.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(i).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You set the count to reference SeriesCollection(1). But then in the loop that counts (i = 1 to count), you reference SeriesCollection(2), which is the datalabel collection for the next data series, not the one you selected.

Comment: These "2" and "1" are dummy values. I just want to apply my code on the selected dataseries in chart in powerpoint. Please let me know if you can assist. thanks